# Empty Fields in Database

Tags: mysql

Can someone explain me please why I am getting empty fields stored in database for title and article. I added if empty statement for title and article, but looks like something does not work.. empty fields are still stored in the database..

I also tried with if(isset($_POST['submit'])  && !empty($_POST["submit"])) but without success..

Any suggestion??

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $date_added = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $author = $_POST['author'];

if(empty($_POST['title'])) {

    echo "title is required";

    } else {

    $title = $_POST['title'];

    }

if(empty($_POST['article'])) {

    echo "article is required";

    } else {

    $article = $_POST['article'];

    }

    $query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO posts (date_added, title, article, author) VALUES ('$date_added', '$title', '$article', '$author')");

    if(!$query) {
        die("QUERY FAILED" . " " . mysqli_error($con));

    }
}
```

Thank you ..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **empty** means it is set even though it is empty.

You need to try this:

```
if($_POST['article']=="" || $_POST['article']==null )
```